# C# ComboBox OwnerDrawFixed vertical alignment

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a combobox in `OwnerDrawFixed`.

This is the code I used to create the elements inside. I want to know how I can text align to centre?

As you can see from the Image I can't centrally align it.

Can you help me?

```cs
private void cboFields_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    using (StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat()
    {
        Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    })
    {
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.MenuHighlight, e.Bounds);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                                    e.Font, SystemBrushes.HighlightText, e.Bounds, fmt);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                                    e.Font, SystemBrushes.MenuText, e.Bounds, fmt);
        }
    }

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();

}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not possible.  Ownerdraw only applies to the items in the dropdown list, you can't do anything to affect the text alignment of the textbox portion of the control.  Otherwise the basic reason why this is not a built-in feature.

Comment: `comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;`  Do favor TextRenderer.DrawText over e.Graphics.DrawString when drawing on the screen.

Comment: @LarsTech Ty i have solved as you told me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with `DropDownStyle = DropDownList`. Note that you will get an `e.Index == -1` when the text box part has to be drawn. Then get the text from `comboBox1.Text`.

`e.DrawBackground();` automatically draws the right background color for selected and not selected entries.

`e.ForeColor` automatically returns the right text color for selected and not selected entries.

```
private void ComboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    const TextFormatFlags flags =
        TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;

    e.DrawBackground();

    string text = e.Index >= 0 ? comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString() : comboBox1.Text;
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.Font, e.Bounds, e.ForeColor, flags);

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

`TextRenderer` gives better results and simplifies aligning the text by specifying flags. You can also combine other flags. E.g. `TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis` draws "..." to the right when the text does not fit.

The reason it does not work with `DropDownStyle = DropDown` is that you can edit the text box part. Therefore only a part of the text might be selected during edits, requiring a more complex drawing logic.